# Separating integrals to solve difficult problems

Tags: integration

If I have the integral of f(x)g(x) by dx can I do the integrals separately and multiply the products together ? i.e is it true that 
$$\int f(x)g(x)  dx=(\int f(x) dx).(\int g(x)dx)?$$

Comment: Νο, that can't happen.

Comment: So the only way would be by parts

Comment: Integrating by parts is usually the first thing to try.

Comment: No, in general $\int f(x)g(x)dx \neq \int f(x)dx \cdot \int g(x)dx$.

Comment: @darren Integrating by parts is not the only way to deal with such problems. For example, you might have a special case of the form:
$$\displaystyle \int f'(g(x)) \cdot g'(x) \, dx = f(g(x)) + \mathrm{constant}$$

Answer (score 1):

No, let $f(x)=g(x)=x$, so that
$$\int x^2 dx= \frac{x^3}3\neq (\frac{x^2}2)(\frac{x^2}2)= (\int x dx)(\int x dx)$$

Answer (score 0):

We have

$$ D(f(x)g(x)) = f'(x)g(x) + f(x)g'(x)$$

then

$$ \int D(f(x)g(x) dx = \int \left( f'(x)g(x) + f(x)g'(x)\right) dx =\int f'(x)g(x) dx + \int f(x)g'(x)dx $$

since $\int D(f(x)g(x) dx = f(x)g(x)$ one can rearrange to get

$$ \int f'(x)g(x) dx = f(x)g(x) - \int f(x)g'(x) dx$$